# I want to design a container which holds 3 divs inline holding parents property

Tags: html, css

In my container i put border-radius , but whenever i align 3 divs inline inside the container, the border-radius is gonna lost.Container divides into 3 parts but it takes the whole height on container and the border-radius i give is lost under the child. Actually i want the child one left side and child right side will  get the radius in up and down.
HTML code:

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background: black;
  margin: 50px auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

.child1 {
  background: white;
  height: 100%;
  width: 33.3%;
  float: left;
}

.child2 {
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 33.3%;
  float: left;
}

.child3 {
  background: blue;
  height: 100%;
  width: 33.3%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child1">
  </div>
  <div class="child2">
  </div>
  <div class="child3">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow: hidden` to the container.

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  overflow: hidden; /* this will enforce the appearance of border-radius */
  background: black;
  margin: 50px auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

.child1 {
  background: green;
  height: 100%;
  width: 33.3%;
  float: left;
}

.child2 {
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 33.3%;
  float: left;
}

.child3 {
  background: blue;
  height: 100%;
  width: 33.3%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child1">
  </div>
  <div class="child2">
  </div>
  <div class="child3">
  </div>
</div>
```